# Custom boot logo without custom kernel?

Tags: systemd, boot, graphics, initramfs, plymouth

If you build a custom Linux kernel, you can include a custom logo image that is displayed almost immediately on boot, followed by the regular boot messages (or Plymouth boot graphic).

Is there some way to compile an image into the initramfs and get a very-early-run systemd service (or initramfs script) to do the equivalent, avoiding the need to compile a custom kernel?

I usually find that there's a surprisingly long time before the Plymouth graphic appears (and then it doesn't stay up long before replaced with the X login), and I'm hoping to bridge that gap.

Essentially I guess what I'm looking for is something that can display an image directly in the default framebuffer terminal (as an actual image, not a text approximation) and then have regular text output from other systemd messages below it.  And which has minimal dependencies so that it will run from an initramfs.

Alternatively, a way to make the Plymouth screen appear sooner.

Comment: Possibly useful for systems with Intel graphics: flicker free boot (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526024/70524, https://hansdegoede.livejournal.com/19224.html)