# Is it possible to configure GRUB to remove UEFI vendor logo faster during boot?

Tags: fedora, grub2, uefi, framebuffer

I appreciate the [flicker free boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526024/423679) feature of Fedora. However, I am a disappointed customer of my laptop manufacturer. I would like to see less of its logo, so that I could dwell less on my regrets. So I followed the advice from Hans de Goede on [getting rid of the vendor-logo or firmware-splash being shown while Fedora is booting](https://hansdegoede.livejournal.com/20632.html).

I managed to stop Plymouth from showing the OEM logo by changing its theme from the default `bgrt` to `spinner`, which is just the same but only without the vendor logo.

```
$ sudo plymouth-set-default-theme -R spinner
```

Next, I added `video=efifb:nobgrt` to kernel commandline, so that the kernel does not restore the vendor logo. Doing this removed the logo appearing in the short timeframe right after accessing the GRUB menu, for example with <kbd>F8</kbd>, before Plymouth splash.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
$ grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rhgb quiet video=efifb:nobgrt"
$ sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2-efi.cfg
```

However, if I do not access GRUB, so that it remains [hidden](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/HiddenGrubMenu), there is no black screen period between the firmware logo and the Plymouth splash.

Adding `fbcon=nodefer` forces the kernel to [takeover framebuffer earlier](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/fb/fbcon.html?highlight=nodefer), so it clears the vendor logo a few seconds earlier:

> 6. fbcon=nodefer
>
>    If the kernel is compiled with deferred fbcon takeover support, normally the framebuffer contents, left in place by the firmware/bootloader, will be preserved until there actually is some text is output to the console. This option causes fbcon to bind immediately to the fbdev device.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
$ grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rhgb quiet video=efifb:nobgrt fbcon=nodefer"
$ sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2-efi.cfg
```

Now, there are a few seconds of black screen before Plymouth splash.

However, I assume that GRUB, being silent, does not redraw the screen, so the firmware screen probably perpetuates a few seconds longer. Is it possible to tweak GRUB to immediately force blank screen after UEFI loading it?

---

*Update*: During boot, there is a barely noticeable flick of the screen in the beginning while the OEM logo is there. If I press <kbd>F8</kbd> during boot, GRUB appears approximately at the same time that the flick would occur. So, I guess that GRUB can overtake the screen faster. The question is how to configure it to do so.

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rhgb quiet video=efifb:nobgrt fbcon=nodefer"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
```

I looked through the BIOS settings for options that might hide the logo, so that it would not appear in the first place. I tried disabling fastboot and enabling the boot menu during POST. Neither had any apparent effect at all. If there is a way to configure it from the operating system to remove the logo during boot, that would solve my issue too.

Comment: My computer has a setting in BIOS that disables "fast boot" and shows diagnostics info instead of the logo. Have you looked for something like that?