# Is there a way to change the font style and size of texts from boot up like "Loading intitial ramdisk"?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, bios

I have an Aorus motherboard and what I've noticed was that when I installed Ubuntu, the Aorus logo when booting up was less-pixelated and there was even a spinner that looked cute and cool. Like here
[image: Aorus]

I'm currently on Arch and even the fonts after the boot up, like since I use startx, the fonts from the login seems pretty small. Is there anyway I could achieve the spinner in logo thingy and how do I increase the font style/size in the login? Which topic should I search and read for?

Comment: I’m not familiar enough with Arch to determine what needs to be fixed, but this is called [flicker-free boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526024/86440) and [should be supported on Arch](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=255691).

Comment: i found something called "plymouth" on arch, but it isn't quite what i've been looking for, i still want to disable those "loading initial ramdisk" and stuffs when booting up @StephenKitt

Comment: Try:
Resize font on boot message screen and console. https://askubuntu.com/questions/548522/resize-font-on-boot-message-screen-and-console